# Use awk in python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, awk

I have to use awk print inside python script.

Below format I used

```
  a = commands.getoutput(" ls -l | awk \'{print $1, $2}\' | awk \'{if(NR>3)print}\'"
```

I am getting below error:

```
 KeyError: 'print $1, $2'
```

Can some one help me to fix.

Comment: List the full function arguments. Are you calling `.format()` somewhere in that line?

Comment: The `commands` module is long since deprecated.  None of this is hard to do natively in Python itself.

Comment: yes i am calling .format()

Comment: `I have to use awk print inside python script.`. No you don't. There's nothing here that you couldn't do in Python.

Comment: As others have said, you can do this operation in Python. Doing it by calling awk inside a shell pipeline is silly. Besides, even if you were doing this in a Bash script or directly in the terminal it's considered bad practice to parse the output of `ls`, as mentioned in [BashGuide's ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and in [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/88378).

Comment: However, if you don't care about not parsing `ls` output, you can simplify that awk stuff: `ls -l | awk 'NR>3{print $1, $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Your Awk scripts can be simplified to a single script trivially.  There is nothing here which really calls for using Awk anyway.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
with Popen(["ls", "-l"], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
    for index, line in enumerate(proc.stdout):
        if index <= 2:
            continue
        print(' '.join(line.split()[0:2]))
```